# Как заполнить контентом блоки разной высоты?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Есть 2 div'а, назовём их **А** и **B**. **А** содержит контент не известной заранее высоты, от 2 строк текста до 3 прокруток экрана. **B** располагается рядом с **A** (боковая панелька) и содержит в себе любое количество контента примерно известной высоты, например div'ы от 200px до 300px высотой, тоже все разные до жути.

Нужно уравновесить блок **A** соседним — отобразить столько блоков внутри **B**, чтобы в итоге они получились примерно равными (±150px). Сами блоки делать равной высоты задача не стоит. Если есть решение без js — хотелось бы его тоже увидеть.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Хотя задача сформулирована достаточно хорошо, однако с точки зрения конечной реализации она позволяет несколько трактовок: уточните, откуда берутся блоки в __B__ - это фиксированный ли это набор блоков, ограничено ли их количество, априори ли их достаточно, можно ли их сортировать в произвольном порядке.

Comment: B - фиксированный набор блоков, несортируемый. Их можно генерировать любое количество т.е. их всегда "достаточно".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Отображаем полностью **A** и пустой - **B**. Вычисляем высоту **A**.
2. В отдельном, скрытом (не `display: none` а именно `visibility: hidden` или `opacity: 0` и `position: absolute`) блоке **C** отображаем блоки из которых можно выбирать (либо же используем **C** в дальнейшем как буфер, если таковых может быть слишком много, заполняя его соответственно на шаге 3). Ширину **C** устанавливаем ширине **B**
3. Запускаем цикл с [перебором комбинаций](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array) высот блоков из **C**, пока не найдена достаточно близкая к высоте **A**, величина их суммы.
4. Добавляем найденную комбинацию блоков в **B**

Технически, разумно подгружать в **C** следующий блок только с целью получения его высоты, а главное назначение **C** - его контент невидим и не должен влиять на скроллинг в момент перебора, но его высоту и высоту любого вложенного в него блока, можно получить.

На CSS есть возможность выровнять по высоте сами колнки **A** и **B** несколькими способами:

1. http://vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/
2. http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways

Comment: Спасибо, это близко к тому о чём думал. А нет возможности прятать "лишние" блоки без дополнительных конструкций и временного блока C? (может css умеет и я полезное свойство упускаю) Как я уточнил чуть выше — мы можем нагенерировать в B любое количество блоков и они у нас не перемешиваются т.е. нас интересует именно тот момент, когда "хватит уже", итоговые столбцы A и B должны свободно болтаться рядом, не выравнивая высоту пустым местом, только контентом.

Comment: Как ещё один вариант я рассматривал сделать B высотой с A + разбежка, отрезать лишние блоки, которые не влезают (тут уже небольшие затруднения реализации), потом вернуть B свободную высоту. Но тоже не отпускает мысль о том что должно быть проще.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону свойства `display: flex;`. [Полная документация](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox). Пример реализации:

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background:#000;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```